# I have a Asus G55V laptop and I was wondering which Ubuntu Version I should go for?

Tags: laptop, asus, versions

As the title says, I have a Asus G55V laptop and I was basically wondering which Ubuntu version I should go for. A year ago or so was the first time I decided to try Ubuntu, I had a different laptop back than and I remember encounting some problems installing and getting the newer versions that was available back then to work on my laptop. After asking for help on a forum I was told to go for Ubuntu 10.04, which worked perfectly for me. The laptop currently has Windows 7 installed from the factory, and I feel that Im really urging to get back to using Ubuntu.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a high spec laptop, so you can choose between any of the different flavors of Ubuntu. Since you don't have a lot of experience with Ubuntu, I recommend that you install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS which is supported by updates until April, 2017. That way you get a stable Long Term Support release that won't need an upgrade or a new install until April, 2017.

The other available alternative choices are Ubuntu 12.10, which is supported by updates until April, 2014, and Ubuntu 13.04, which is supported by updates until January, 2014.